# Say a function is differentiable on (0,1], does $TV(f)=\int_0^1|f'|$ hold

Tags: real-analysis

Say a function is differentiable on (0,1], does $TV(f)=\int_0^1|f'|$ hold? So if $f$ is differentiable on $[0,1]$ the result is clear using MVT and the definition of a Riemann sum. However, does the result hold when we consider the Lebesgue integral and $f'$ is defined only on $(0,1]$. I have tried a couple of functions and it seems to work, i just do not know how to prove it

Answer (score 0):

"if $f$ is differentiable on on $[0,1]$ the result is clear using MVT and the definition of a reimann sum." No, it can fail with respect to the Riemann integral for $f$ differentiable on $[0,1].$ There is a well known example of a differentiable, strictly increasing, positive function on $[0,1],$ with $f'$ bounded but $f'=0$ on a dense set. For this $f,$ $f'=|f'|$ fails to be Riemann integrable.

Comment: where does the argument fail then? $|f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})|=|f'(c_i)|(x_i-x_{i-1})$ and you take the sup over the partitions. Perhaps using lebesgue integral would work then, since $f'$ of such a function would be integrable in the lebesgue sense.

Comment: The argument fails because you are assuming $|f'|$ is Riemann integrable which it need not be. Yes, the result holds if the Lebesgue integral is used.

Comment: In this case it was not reimann integrable, then we can conclude it is not BV, correct?

Comment: No, the counterexample is strictly increasing, hence in BV.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pompeiu_derivative

Comment: Well since it is strictly increasing should not the derivative be bigger than 0 everywhere? What is the fully correct statement and how do you prove it? Should i post a new question?

Comment: No, consider $(x-1/2)^3$